# Create an array from range elements with a base array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$baseArray = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 );
```

So i want to make two arrays of range

```
$arrayOne = from index 5 - 10
$arrayTwo = from index 15 - 20
```

How can I split the $baseArray to make arrays like that in php ?

Comment: Did you read any of the [php.net](http://php.net) documentation ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I tried array_chunk function and array_slice but no result.

Comment: @Mihaiiorga I read but the functions I used did not worked

Comment: There is native function [array_alice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Only works if you have an index with numbers start's with 0)

```
$baseArray = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 );
$arrayOne = array();
$arrayTwo = array();

foreach($baseArray as $k => $v) {

    if($k >= 5 && $k <= 10)
        $arrayOne[] = $v;
    elseif($k >= 15 && $k <= 20)
        $arrayTwo[] = $v;

}

print_r($arrayOne);
print_r($arrayTwo);
```

Output:

arrayOne:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 11
)
```

arrayTwo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 18
    [3] => 19
    [4] => 20
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is function [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$baseArray = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 );
$arrayOne = array_slice($baseArray, 5, 10);
$arrayTwo = array_slice($baseArray, 15, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try using `for()` & `array_slice()`. Example:

```
$baseArray = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 );
$newAr = array();
for($i = 5; $i < count($baseArray); $i += 10){
    $newAr[] = array_slice($baseArray, $i, 5);
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($newAr);
print '</pre>';
```